# NameError: global name 'e' is not defined(pyjamas)

Tags: python-2.7, pyjamas

i am installed pyjamas as yum install pyjamas on fedora19

The following file i executed

### hello.py

```
from pyjamas.ui.RootPanel import RootPanel
from pyjamas.ui.Label import Label

l = Label('Hello pyjs')
RootPanel().add(l)
```

when i am building the js file

```
 pyjsbuild hello.py
```

i am getting following error

```
Building: hello
PYJSPATH: ['/home/iton/Desktop/night',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyjs-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/pyjswidgets',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyjs-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/pyjswaddons',
'/usr/share/pyjamas/library',
'/usr/share/pyjamas/addons']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pyjsbuild", line 21, in <module>
pyjs.browser.build_script()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyjs-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/pyjs/browser.py", line 524, in    build_script
runtime_options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyjs-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/pyjs/browser.py", line 448, in build
l()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyjs-0.8.2-py2.7.egg/pyjs/linker.py", line 267, in __call__
except translator.TranslationError( e ):
NameError: global name 'e' is not defined
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is broken by the last two commits. Moved back by two commits the build is working.

```
git clone https://github.com/pyjs/pyjs
cd pyjs
git checkout 564cf5f
```

The working version was on Mar 20 2014.